# How to pass variables from a .env file to Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `.env` file with a large list of variables in the root of my node project. In the root is also my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

I'm trying to pass in these variables to Docker ([from here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#setting-environment-variables-in-containers)), but when I run `docker-compose up`, I'm running into an error in my node app because it doesn't have access to these variables. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the error (redacting any secrets of course) and confirm your .env file consists of KEY=VALUE pairs? There is a difference between arguments and environment variables and when they're available in the image & container. I'm wondering if this error occurs during the build phase or after container start.

Answer (score 3):

Change the file name to something different like `node.env`. The `.env` file is used by the docker-compose itself to define the content of the docker-compose file itself.

Example:

```
$ cat .env
TAG=v1.5

$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: "webapp:${TAG}"
```

The content of this file is not used inside the docker instance itself.